# How to create RCP project without a workspace and other Eclipse default features?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How to create RCP project without a workspace and other Eclipse default features?

Each time I create Eclipse RCP project, it runs in separate workspace, shows Package Explorer at left, allows to create projects and so on.

Is it possible to create standalone applications like XMind, which just open files of certain types and contain views of certain types?

**UPDATE**

For example, there is a Zest sample just inside Eclipse help. It is intended to run under Eclipse, but contains main:

```
/*******************************************************************************
  * Copyright 2005-2007, CHISEL Group, University of Victoria, Victoria, BC,
  * Canada. All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials are
  * made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which
  * accompanies this distribution, and is available at
  * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
  * 
  * Contributors: The Chisel Group, University of Victoria
  ******************************************************************************/
 package org.eclipse.zest.examples.swt;

 import org.eclipse.zest.core.widgets.Graph;
 import org.eclipse.zest.core.widgets.GraphConnection;
 import org.eclipse.zest.core.widgets.GraphNode;
 import org.eclipse.zest.layouts.LayoutStyles;
 import org.eclipse.zest.layouts.algorithms.SpringLayoutAlgorithm;
 import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
 import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
 import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

 /**
  * This snippet creates a very simple graph where Rock is connected to Paper
  * which is connected to scissors which is connected to rock.
  * 
  * The nodes a layed out using a SpringLayout Algorithm, and they can be moved
  * around.
  * 
  * 
  * @author Ian Bull
  * 
  */
 public class GraphSnippet1 {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the shell
        Display d = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(d);
        shell.setText("GraphSnippet1");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setSize(400, 400);

        Graph g = new Graph(shell, SWT.NONE);
        GraphNode n = new GraphNode(g, SWT.NONE, "Paper");
        GraphNode n2 = new GraphNode(g, SWT.NONE, "Rock");
        GraphNode n3 = new GraphNode(g, SWT.NONE, "Scissors");
        new GraphConnection(g, SWT.NONE, n, n2);
        new GraphConnection(g, SWT.NONE, n2, n3);
        new GraphConnection(g, SWT.NONE, n3, n);
        g.setLayoutAlgorithm(new SpringLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutStyles.NO_LAYOUT_NODE_RESIZING), true);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            while (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
                d.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

How to compile this? If I put it just into java project, it does not have numerous Eclipse libs. But if I create plugin project, I see no place to insert main method.

Comment: In the Run configuration, you can change this behavior, and select only the plugins needed to run your plugins...

Comment: You mean in `Plug-ins` tab of run configuration? Does this mean that I can freely run my app with all eclipse features at development stage and will be able to disable all unneeded later, when production phase?

Comment: How are you creating the RCP project?

Comment: @SuzanCioc yes, you can have all the Eclipse plugins from your installation - if zou need them for debugging purposes. When you create the application, you will be able to fine-tune what to include and what not.

Answer (score 1):

To get the absolute minimum RCP code do `File / New Project` and select `Plug-in Project`. On the second step of the wizard deselect `This plug-in will make contributions to the UI` and select `Yes` for `Would you like to create a 3.x rich client application`. The final step of the wizard will then have a `Headless Hello RCP` which creates the absolute minimum code for a RCP.

If you leave `This plug-in will make contributions to the UI` checked some templates to create RCPs with a view etc. are shown.

The above is for Eclipse 3.x style RCPs, for Eclipse 4 pure `e4` RCPs use `Eclipse 4 / Eclipse 4 Application Project` in New Project wizard.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't achieve final result. In the case of 3.x I can create headless application, which runs headless under Eclipse debugger, but can't make it standalone. Export to runnable JAR does not work for Eclipse project. Concerning Eclipse 4 I was unable to make headless application at all.

Comment: You have to use Export Product to export an Eclipse RCP, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F